# android apk not reading xml file (apk build from unity editor)

Tags: c#, android, xml, internationalization, unity-game-engine

i am developing a multi-language game using unity engine, i have xml files written for each language but android apk doesn't seem to read the xml files where as the PC platform build works fine with all the languages.

Here is my code:

```
void Awake()
{
    languagePath = Application.dataPath + "/Languages/";
    CollectLanguages();
}

private void CollectLanguages()
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo langDir = new DirectoryInfo(languagePath);
        FileInfo[] files = langDir.GetFiles("*.xml");
        languageFiles = new string[files.Length];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo fileGo in files)
        {
            languageFiles[i] = fileGo.FullName;
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}

private string GetLanguageFile(string language)
{
    foreach (string langGo in languageFiles)
    {
        if (langGo.EndsWith(language + ".xml"))
        {
            return langGo;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

public void LoadLanguage(string language)
{
    try
    {

        string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + language+".xml";
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            WWW path = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/"+"Languages/"+language+".xml");
            while(!path.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log("Loading File");
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, path.bytes);
        }
        mainDoc = new XmlDocument();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (filepath);
        mainDoc.Load(streamReader);
        root = mainDoc.DocumentElement;
        streamReader.Close();

    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the read and write directory to 
`Application.streamingAssetsPath`

add a new folder in Assets
and name it to **StreamingAssets**
every file under the StreamingAssets can modify , read , write in all of platforms